# Unexpected <EOF> while using graphql

Tags: graphql-js, express-graphql

Getting EOF error every time at same line, changed code many times and even degraded to previous versions of `graphql` but no positive results.
My code is:

```
const graphql = require('graphql')
const _ = require('lodash')
 const {
     GraphQLObjectType,
     GraphQLString,
     GraphQLInt,
     GraphQLSchema
 } = graphql

const users = [
    {id: '1', firstName: 'Ansh', age: 20},
    {id: '2', firstName: 'Ram', age: 21},
    {id: '3', firstName: 'Sham', age: 20}
]

 const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'User',
     fields: {
        id: {type: GraphQLString},
        firstName: {type: GraphQLString},
        age: {type: GraphQLInt}
     }
 })

 const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
     name: 'RootQueryType',
          fields: {
             user: {
                 type: UserType,
                 args: {id: {type: GraphQLString}},
                 resolve(parentValue, args) { 
                    return _.find(users, {id: args.id})
                 }
             }
         }
     })

 module.exports = new GraphQLSchema({
    query: RootQuery 
})
```

Error is:

```
    {
        "errors": [
        {
            "message": "Syntax Error GraphQL request (30:1) Unexpected <EOF>\n\n29: \n30: \n    ^\n",
            "locations": [
            {
                "line": 30,
                "column": 1
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is because the query you're passing might be empty.

For example:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/graphql \ 
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"query": "{ user { id } }"}'
```

works fine.

But if you make something like:

```
curl -X POST http://localhost:4000/graphql \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"query": ""}'
```

You'll get *unexpected < EOF >*

Also, check [GraphQL end of line issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/77#issuecomment-131446042).

Answer (score 3):

I had comments in the *schema.graphql* file:

```
"""
Some comments
"""
```

I removed the comments and the `Unexpected <EOF>` error went away.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there's no actual query so you get unexpected EOF (End of File).

Guessing that you're using GraphiQL (because your EOF message says line 30); you need to add a query on the left-hand panel of GraphiQL in the browser. Something which conforms to your `RootQuery` like:

```
{
  user(id: "1") {
    id,
    firstName,
    age
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while trying to stitch my schema
the reason for this error was that I delcared a type but didn't implemet it, had empty body, for example:

```
type User {

}
```

implementing the type fixed it

Comment: where did you add this?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like if we are doing the schema-first approach, but we do not have any .graphql files in your project/empty. I added this and the error went away:

`src/example.graphql`

```
type Query {
  hello: String
}
```

The "GraphQLError: Syntax Error: `Unexpected` " error is coming from the graphql package. It looks like `@nestjs/graphql` is assuming that there will always be at least one .graphql file, so this is probably a bug to try and parse an empty schema vs display a more developer-friendly message or ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases passing an empty query is caused to this error.
To avoid this try this in your graphiql

```
query { 
   user {
     fields you need to retrieve
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because your `graphql.gql` looks like this:

```
# ------------------------------------------------------
# THIS FILE WAS AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED (DO NOT MODIFY)
# ------------------------------------------------------

directive @key(fields: String!) on OBJECT | INTERFACE

directive @extends on OBJECT | INTERFACE

directive @external on OBJECT | FIELD_DEFINITION

directive @requires(fields: String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION

directive @provides(fields: String!) on FIELD_DEFINITION
```

One thing you can do is create a dummy resolver.

```
// src/graphql/resolvers/user.resolver.ts

import { Resolver, Query } from '@nestjs/graphql';

import { User } from 'models/User.model';

@Resolver(() => User)
export class UserResolver {
  @Query(() => User)
  async ids() {
    return [];
  }
}
```

and create a graphql model:

```
// src/graphql/models

import { Field, ObjectType } from '@nestjs/graphql';

@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field()
  createdAt: Date;
}
```

And make sure that resolver is imported by a module and the module is added to App.module

This should fix it!

Answer (score 0):

In my case on the frontend side (Angular), since I just wanted to observe something, I have this code:
[image]

I got this error:

```
Error: Unexpected <EOF>.
```

and I made it comment-line  and the error was gone

Answer (score -1):

**How to fix it:** Go to `node_mudules > graphql > syntaxError.js` and delete all comments from this file and the error should be gone.